# Global find replace in SSIS 2008 and 2012

Tags: ssis

I have several hundred SSIS pkgs, and I need to change one of the connection mangers per package from a SQL Server connection to another DB platform (ODBC).  I found this [link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/lucaz/archive/2012/06/05/how-to-update-all-the-ssis-packagesrsquo-connection-managers-in.aspx) and think I can make it work.  But I wondered if it was possible to use a tool like notepad++ or the like to open all of them at the same time and do a global find/replace with the connection manager.  This would also need to be done to translate all the TSQL to the new DB platform SQL.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?   They are just text files.

Comment: Correct, I could open each file individually, then do a global find/replace and hope it all works out.  I am looking for a more automated, possibly with error checking solution.  Like an example of a BIML Script.